# the word "right" adjective or adverb in the sentence

Tags: word-usage

> It  was  easy  to  take  10  days  away  from  the  calendar.  This  made  it  **right**  with  the  sun  again. There was still a problem: how to keep the calendar right in the future, year after year.

In this sentence, I can't decide  whether **right** is adverb or adjective in "make it right with the sun".

Comment: Is this some kind of idiom?

Comment: It's an adjective here. It functions as object complement of "make" and relates to the direct object "it" (which is anaphoric to "calendar"). Adverbs cannot normally function as predicative complements. Note that the PP "with the sun again" is complement to "right"; together they form the adjective phrase "right with the sun again".

Answer (score 1):

"make it right" is an idiom which means to correct something or make it the way it should be.

Other variations of the idiom are:

- set it right
- make it good
- put it right